# Adding primary keys to a production database

Tags: sql-server, database-design, database-schema, production-environment

I just inherited a relatively small SQL Server database. We have a decentralized system operating on about ten sites, with each site being pounded all day by between sixty and one hundred clients. Upon inspecting the system, a couple of things jumped out at me: there are no maintenance plans or keys defined.

I have dozens of different applications that are already accessing the database. The majority of them are written in C with inline SQL. Part of what I was brought in to do was write stored procedures for everything and have our applications move to that. Before I do this, however, I really think I should be focusing on these seemingly glaring issues.

Also, we'll eventually be looking into replication to a central site, so I really think these things should be addressed before we even think of that.

Figuring out a redesign scheme and maintenance plan will be time-consuming but not problematic - I've done it before at single sites. But, how am I going to go about implementing these major changes to the database across ten (or more) production sites while ensuring data integrity and not breaking the applications?

Comment: relevant to the answer: if there are no keys defined how is replication done? (for that matter if there are reeeeeeealy no keys, how do you update any records?)

Comment: There is no replication at this time. Also, there are logical keys -- customer numbers, for instance. However, no primary keys have been defined in the database, so updates are just ran against the database using those types of values.

Comment: when you say logical, you mean unique keys? Also do you by any chance have clustered indexes on these tables?

Comment: I mean that while records are made unique in the application layer (for instance, with an incrementing customer ID) there is nothing defined in the database to enforce integrity - no primary keys, no unique constraints, etc. So while I know that records are generally unique due to what's going on in the application layer, I have no enforcement at the database level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suspect that with no keys officaly defined, that this database probaly has tons of data integrity problems. Lucky you.

For replication you will need GUIDs. I would do this, Add the GUIDs and PK definitions in the dev environment and test test test. You'll prbably find alot of crap where people did select * and adding the columns will cause probnalem or cause things to show up on reports that you don't want.  Find and fix all these things. Be sure to script allthe changes to the data and put them in source control along with any code changes you need to make to the application. Then schedule down time for maintenance of the database during the lowest usage hours. Let the users know the application will be down ahead of time.  During the down time, have the application show a down message, change the datbase to single user mode so no one except the team making this change can affect the database, make a fullbackup, run the scripts to make the changes to the database, run the code to change the application, test, take the database out of single user mode and turn the application back on.

Under no circumstances would I try to make a change this major without going to single user mode.

Comment: To help mitigate some of the app issues with `SELECT *` or field number changes, he could make a view with the name of the old table, rename the source table, and only include the original fields in the view.

Answer (score 2):

First ensure you have valid backups of every db, and test-restore them to make sure they restore OK.

Consider using Ola Hallengren's maintenance vs. Maintenance Plans if you need to deploy identical, consistent, scripted solutions to all your sites ([Ola Hallengren's site](http://ola.hallengren.com/))

Then I'd say look at getting some basic indexing in place, starting with heavy-hitter tables first.  You can identify them with various methods - presume you know how, but just to throw a few out thoughts:  code review, SQL Trace, Query Plan analysis, and then there are 3rd party tools e.g., Idera SQLdm, Confio Ignite, Quest's Spotlight on SQL Server or Foglight Performance Analysis for SQL Server.

I think this will get you rolling.

Answer (score 1):

Some additional ideas.

One of the first thing's I'd check is: are all the database instances alike, as far as database *objects* are concerned? Do they all have the exact same tables, columns (and their order in the tables), nullability, etc. etc. Be sure to check pretty much everything listed in sys.objects. Once you know that the database structures are all in synch, then you know that any database modification scripts you generate will work on all the instances.

Once you modify your test environment with your planned changes, you have to ensure that they don't break existing functionality. Can you accurately emulate "...being pounded all day by between sixty and one hundred clients" on your test environment? If you can't, then you of course cannot know if your changes will break anything until they go live. (An assumption I'd avoid: just because a given instance *has* no duplicates in the columns you wish to build a primary key on does not mean that there are *never* any duplicates present...)